# Change menu text android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have a string that i get from asynctask, i would like to set that string as title of menu item in actionbar.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        this.menu = menu;

        if (menu!= null) {
               menu.findItem(R.id.azzera).setVisible(false);
            }

        MenuItem giornataItem = menu.findItem(R.id.giornata);
        giornataItem.setTitle(giornataTitle);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view

        MenuItem giornataItem = menu.findItem(R.id.giornata);
        giornataItem.setTitle(giornataTitle);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

OnPrepareOptionsMenu works fine, when i change fragment or drawernav is open the title is still correct, but onCreateOptionsMenu does not set the title on application start because in that moment the string is null, because it's called before asynctask.
How can i set that string as title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call asynctask while create menu

```
    String tital=new Asynctask().execute("").get();

    MenuItem giornataItem = menu.findItem(R.id.giornata);
    giornataItem.setTitle(tital);
```

if you are talking about making a string to tital of your activity

then call

```
 String tital=new Asynctask().execute("").get();
 setTitle(tital);

 setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);
```

Comment: Still does not work. I'm talking about making a string as title of menu item in actionbar @raj

Comment: then show your activity code where you creating actionbar

Comment: Calling invalidateOptionsMenu() in onPostTaskExecute of AsyncTask did the trick, thank you!